# Network card error while creating Solars 11 VM on hyper-v

Tags: virtual-machine, solaris, hyper-v

I am trying to create Solaris 11 VM on hyper-v.
While installing Solaris I get following message:
No Network interface found , addition driver may be needed.

When installation is done , My IP is not configured in machine.
I found one link where same problem is mention but solution is not clear to me.
https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4282130/solaris-11-4-installation-in-hyper-v

Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open up VMWare Workstation, or your VMware app, Go to Settings for your VM, and look for "Network Adapter".

The default is NAT. If that doesn't work, try bridged, or cycle through the options to see if any are supported.

If that doesn't work, you may need to add a new network device. In that case, you will need to do this:

Select Window > Virtual Machine Library.

Select a virtual machine in the Virtual Machine Library window and click Settings.

Click Add Device.

Click Network Adapter.

Click Add.